# How to rewrite two GET values on htaccess and mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just want to make the GET information that I sent:

http://mywebsite.com/folder/index.php?category=category-alias-here
http://mywebsite.com/folder/index.php?category=category-alias-here&page=5

To be rewrited on the URL bar as:

http://mywebsite.com/folder/category-alias-here/

http://mywebsite.com/folder/category-alias-here/5/

And I cant. Its very simple, I saw several similar questions. Tested several examples on stackoverflow and they all give me 404 for both category and both pages.

Here is a code that I tested:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

I understand that this code be wrong for my structure specifically, I tried several changes placing and removing ([^/]+) or changed the fist [L] to [N]. And several other things. But no luck with that.

Please notice, the whole website is inside a real directory (/folder/) and the .htaccess is also there (its not on root), once I launch the website everything will be on public_html, but I do not think this is the reason of this issue.

And yes, mod_rewrite is on. There is actually a .htaccess that I use, it works anywhere I place and it gets the category correctly but it is a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)\/([0-9-]+)\/$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\/$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```